# Can a function have `multiple optional parameters' that is simultaneously required?

Tags: typescript

I'm currently trying to polyfill [`createImageBitmap`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#images) function.

```
[NoInterfaceObject, Exposed=Window,Worker]
interface ImageBitmapFactories {
  Promise createImageBitmap(ImageBitmapSource image, optional long sx, long sy, long sw, long sh);
};
```

It seems that this function allows `createImageBitmap(image)` and `createImageBitmap(image, sx, sy, sw, sh)` but not else, for example, `createImageBitmap(image, 0, 0)`.

How can I do this in TypeScript? I cannot do this by:

```
function createImageBitmap(image: any, sx?: number, sy: number, width: number, height: number) { }
```

... as this fails to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need function overloading:

```
function createImageBitmap(image: any);
function createImageBitmap(image: any, sx: number, sy: number, width: number, height: number);
function createImageBitmap(image: any, sx?: number, sy?: number, width?: number, height?: number) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, @basarat already mentioned function overloading but I couldn't bring this method to mind... I think this code is exactly what I want. Thank you :)

Comment: @KagamiSaschaRosylight He did, but his use of method overloading was incorrect. Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

You would need function *overloading*:

```
declare function createImageBitmap(image: any, sx: number, sy: number, width: number, height: number);
declare function createImageBitmap(image: any, sy: number, width: number, height: number);
```

But I think you have the declaration wrong. all x,y,w,h are optional:

[image]

Comment: The specified algorithm checks whether sx, sy, sw, sh are omitted, and uses ALL of them when they are not omitted. Yes, they are all optional. Here, I want to allow just `createImageBitmap(image)`, or `createImageBitmap(image, sx, sy, sw, sh)`, not else. It seems giving partial size parameters is just useless here, for example, `createImageBitmap(image, sx)` - This gives just sx, but what can we do only with x coordinate?